# How to add custom css in luma theme in magento 2.1.2

Tags: magento2, xml, css

Hi As Below path i have added code ,

`app\design\frontend\Magento\luma\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <css src="css/styles-m.css"/>
        <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
        <css src="css/print.css" media="print"/>
        <css src="Magento_Catalog::css/custom.css"/>
        <css src="Magento_Catalog::css/responsive.css"/>
        <css src="Magento_Catalog::css/owl.carousel.css"/>
        <css src="Magento_Catalog::css/owl.carousel.theme.css"/>
        <css src="Magento_Catalog::css/font-awesome.min.css"/>


        <!--<script src="Magento_Catalog::js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
        <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/custom.js"></script>  


        <link src="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900" src_type="url" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Also **CSS** And **JS** File As Below Path

`app\design\frontend\Magento\luma\web\css`

`app\design\frontend\Magento\luma\web\js`

After run command as

- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Now On frontend no show me file .please help .

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can call your css and js by using **Vendorname_Modulename** in in the head block. **So you need to pass Vendorname_Modulename**

Try below code in your layout.xml file :

```
<head>
        <css src="Vendorname_Modulename/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>   
</head>
```

Make sure your css and js location are correct .

```
app\design\frontend\Magento\luma\Vendorname_Modulename\web\css\yourcss.css

app\design\frontend\Magento\luma\Vendorname_Modulename\web\js\yourjs.js
```

After that run below commands :

```
php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I am Passing Magento_Theme as Vendorname_Modulename , But not working .

Comment: Have you checked your custom theme is active for the store you are checking ? also remove var/generation and pub/static/frontend directory and then run setup:di:compile and setup-static:content:deploy and check it will works ,also pass your custom theme vendorname and theme name.

Comment: Yes , I have checked . magento/luma theme is activated all store.

Comment: if you have puted your css file - app\design\frontend\Magento\luma\web\css here then you need to call it like - <head>
        <css src="Magento_luma/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>   
</head>

Answer (score 2):

Add css and js in below respected folder:

```
app\design\frontend\Magento\luma\Magento_Catalog\web\css
```

and

```
app\design\frontend\Magento\luma\Magento_Catalog\web\js
```

After run below commands:

```
 - php bin/magento cache:clean
 - php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Hi I am try with both Magento_Catalog and  Magento_Theme But not working .

Comment: Remove `pub/static/frontend` and `var` folder and run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command.

Comment: Nothing change as i was removed both folder.

Comment: Don't change the code which you have mentioned in your question.
Just add your `css` and `js` in `Magento_Catalog` respected folder.

Comment: i m getting custom.css file at \pub\static\frontend\Magento\luma\en_US\css\custom.css , but on home page view page source not showing me .

Answer (score 0):

To add CSS file follow the below steps:

```
Open File
app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\page.xml
Add the below tag for css:
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/[filename].css</stylesheet></action>

Just below the last method=”addCss” add the above line.
Now open,
skin\frontend\rwd\default\css\[filename].css

Start writing your css code in this file.
```

To add JS file follow the below steps.

```
Open File
app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\page.xml
Add the below tag
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/[filename].js</name></action>

Just below the js include tags similar to the above line.
Now open,
skin\frontend\rwd\default\js\[filename].js

Start writing your js code in this file
```

I hope this will help you!! 
cheers !!